# Problems with final result of planimeter proof

Tags: analysis, greens-theorem

I am referring to this 
[explanation of the polar planimeter, pp. 7](http://www3.amherst.edu/~tleise/Planimeter/LinearAndPolarPlanimeters.pdf)

I think I do understand the following result:

> > During this operation, the wheel on the tracer arm will cover a distance of
> >     $$
> > \frac{b}{L}(x\cos\phi+y\sin\phi-b)d\phi+ad\theta.
> > $$

But I am not sure I did understand why some of these terms seem to vanish when integrating over the curve $C$ 
and what is meant with  $C_1'$ and $C_2'$:

My understanding would be that

$$
\oint_{C}d\phi + d\theta=0
$$
since this is a integral of a total differential $dF$ for $F(\phi,\theta)=\phi + \theta$ over a closed curve and the theory tells me that such integrals vanish. Hence it remains
$$
\frac{b}{L}\oint_C(x\cos\phi+y\sin\phi)d\phi=\frac{b}{L}\oint_{C}x\cos\phi d\phi+\frac{b}{L}\oint_C y\sin\phi d\phi.
$$

Now in the linked article we have instead

> > $$
> > \frac{b}{L}\oint_{C_1'}x\cos\phi d\phi+\frac{b}{L}\oint_{C_2'} y\sin\phi d\phi
> > $$

and I am not sure what $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ are supposed to mean although it is said that $C_1'$ is the curve described by $(x,\phi)$ and $C_2'$ is the curve described by $(\phi,y)$

Maybe the only point that the author wanted to make is that the first integrand somehow depends on $x$ and $\phi$ whereas the second depends on $y$ and $\phi$; maybe thats all.

More formally, if
$$
\gamma=(\gamma_1,\gamma_2)\colon [a,b]\to C
$$
is the parametrization of curve $C$, then maybe the author wanted to say that we have something like $C=C_1'\cup C_2'$, i.e. a part of the curve which is expressed in terms of $x$ and $\phi$ and another which can be expressed in terms of $\phi$ and $y$.

That would be my explanation..

Comment: You didn't link anything...

Comment: I am sorry, I repaired it and added the link.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ follow a path in $\mathbb R^2$, $x,y,\phi$ and $\theta$ follow a path in $\mathbb R^4$; $x$ and $\phi$ follow another path in $\mathbb R^2$. So, strictly speaking, the first integral must be for the path in $\mathbb R^4$ but the author simply gives for granted the dependence of the angles on the coordinates. For the other integrals, not depending on $y$ and $\theta$, uses the path in the configuration space for $x$ and $\phi$. Then $$\frac{b}{L}\oint_{C_1'}x\cos\phi d\phi=\frac{b}{L}\oint_{C}x\cos\phi d\phi$$

Comment: I am not sure if I get your point. C is the curve in $R^2$ over which we want to integrate. And thus, if we let $\phi=\phi(x,y)$ and $\theta=\theta(x,y)$ the integral $\frac{b}{L}\oint_C (x\cos\phi+y\sin\phi-b)d\phi+ad\theta$ makes sense since we really have two variables. But I still do not understand what now $C_1'$ is. It is a curve in $R^2$, but why does this make sense for the integral $\oint_{C_1'}x\cos\phi d\phi$ if $\phi=\phi(x,y)$, i.e. if we have the dependence on $y$ in it?

Comment: Yes, I was not accurate considering what the dependence has to be. As the integrals are written, we have to understand the coordinates as depending on the angles.

Comment: Maybe the idea is that from the picture given in the link, we have something like $\cos\phi = x/b,$, i.e. $\phi=\arccos(x/b)$, and $d\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}dx$ and hence only a dependence of $\phi$ on $x$. Maybe this is meant by "curve described by $(x,\phi)$" which maybe should be written as $(x,\phi(x))$. In other words: A priori we only have $\phi=\phi(x,y)$ but for the integrand $x\cos\phi d\phi$ we know that $\phi$ only depends on $x$ but not on $y$ and this is meant by writing $C_1'$ instead of $C$, because $C$ stands for $\phi=\phi(x,y)$ whereas $C_1'$ stands for $\phi=\phi(x)$?

Comment: Exactly that is.

Comment: Ok, so $C_1'$ is a curve living in the $(x,\phi(x))$ plane and not in the original $xy$-plane.   --- By the way, my idea was that $\oint_{C}d\phi+d\theta=0$ because the integrand is a total differential (is that right?). The author gives another explanation, he says that the reason is that the total angels are both $0$. But in which sense do $\oint_C d\phi$ and $\oint_C d\theta$ represent the total angels? This seems not very mathematically rigorous to me.

Comment: The sentences are equivalent in this case. Being an integral, the total angle has to be understood as the variation total of that angle along some curve; the curve is closed, then the variation is zero.

Comment: I think what you mean is that we can define $\text{total angel}\phi:=\phi(b)-\phi(a)$, where $\gamma\colon [a,b]\to C$ is a parametrization of curve $C$. Then, the equivalence is that $\text{total angel}\phi=0$ if and only if $\oint_C d\phi=\phi(b)-\phi(a)=0$. Hence saying that the total angel is 0 is indeed the same as saying that the integral vanishes. --- Correct?

Comment: addendum: I think another (but non-mathematical) way to explain that the total angels (as defined above) are 0 is the following: After tracing C, the arms are in the same positions from where they started. But by construction of the planimeter, this cannot be happened by making a whole revolution of $2\pi$. Hence we cannot have $\phi(b)=\phi(a)+k2\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and really have $\phi(b)-\phi(a)=0$ (or equivalently: that the integral vanishes). I think this is the argumentation which the author in the linked text does at the end of page 7?

Comment: Exactly! The integral is zero for any parametrization. It **has** to be zero. The argument is mainly classical even though uses integrals: integrals must vanish because the arm reaches its initial point. You are looking for a more rigorous reasoning and you succeed, but the reasoning is not more rigorous, but more analitical. Not a criticism :), simply a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way: The component $ad\theta$ of the distance, is this small-angel approximation, i.e. it is $\sin(d\theta)=x/a\Leftrightarrow x=\sin(d\theta)a$ and we then use that $\sin(d\theta)\approx d\theta$ for small angel $d\theta$?